# Spring with spring.config.location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, config

I am trying to point at path to external configuration file like this:

```
--spring.config.location=file: C:/Users/some_user/workspace/repository1/payment-api/payment.yml
```

and it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The proper prefix is `file://`. On Windows you need an extra "/" in the file URL if it is absolute with a drive prefix

Try `file:///C:/Users/some_user/workspace/repository1/payment-api/payment.yml` instead.